# What is a Cursor and what does it do (in this case)?

Tags: java, android, android-cursor

I have to understand some java code from android studio, but as I'm new to both Java and android I have a question.

Anyone know what Cursor actually is and what does it do exactly in this case?

```
private Movie cursorToMovie (Cursor cursor)
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        movie.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        movie.setGenre(cursor.getString(2));
        movie.setYear(cursor.getInt(3));
        movie.setSynopsis(cursor.getString(4));

        return movie;
    }


    public List<Movie> getAllMovies()
    {
        open();

        List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Movie.TABLE_NAME, MovieAllColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Movie movie = cursorToMovie(cursor);
            movieList.add(movie);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        close();
        return movieList;

    }
```

Comment: You added the android-cursor tag yet failed to read its info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursor is an interface which represents a 2 dimensional table of any database. When you try to retrieve some data using SELECT statement, then the database will first create a Cursor object and return its reference to you.

The pointer of this returned reference is pointing to the 0th location which is otherwise called as before first location of the Cursor, so when you want to retrive data from the cursor, you have to first move to the first record so we have to use moveToFirst

When you invokes moveToFirst() method on the Cursor, it takes the cursor pointer to the first location. Now you can access the data present in the first record

The above code shows that you are trying to read the data but there is some missing information.

Comment: `Cursor`, not `CURSOR`. Also `Cursor` is not a class, it's an interface.

Comment: Thank you for the correction

Comment: Also Cursor data does not have to be from a database. It just provides an interface to a 2 dimensional table of data. Data source could be any and it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html):

> This interface provides random read-write access to the result set
>   returned by a database query.

Note that this description is not totally accurate since the result set (data) doesn't have to be from a database (see [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)).

Comment: If your answer is essentially a pointer to the documentation you might as well not answer and downvote the question for lack of research, to avoid people asking such bad questions

Comment: @TimCastelijns You're right sir.